# How to concatenate feature vectors of different dimensions?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I have been using different deep learning models and extracting features from different layers for the given images. My code goes like this:

```py
#load libraries
from keras import applications
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

#declare models
model1 = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
model1.summary()
model1 = Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=model1.get_layer('block5_conv3').output)
model1.summary()
img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(100,100))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

block5_conv3_features = model1.predict(x) #dimensions (1,6,6,512)

model2 = applications.VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
model2.summary()
model2 = Model(inputs=model2.input, outputs=model2.get_layer('block2_conv1').output)
model2.summary()
img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(100,100))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

block2_conv1_features = model2.predict(x) #dimensions (1,50,50,128)

model3 = applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
model3.summary()
model3 = Model(inputs=model3.input, outputs=model3.get_layer('avg_pool').output)
model3.summary()
img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

preds = model3.predict(x) #dimensions (1,1,1,248)
```

I'm getting feature vectors of dimensions (1,6,6,512), (1,50,50,128) and (1,1,1,128) from three different models. How can I concatenate these feature vectors in Python?

Comment: Did you solve it please